# Using a loop inside a macro

Tags: clojure

Consider this minimal example

```
(defmacro foo []
  `(list ,@(for [i [1 2 3]] (+ 1 i))))
```

I expect `(foo)` to expand to `(list 2 3 4)`

But instead, I get a bunch of indecipherable errors when I try `(macroexpand-1 (foo)`

```
Syntax error macroexpanding clojure.core/let at (*cider-repl <filepath>:localhost:43203(clj)*:366:22).
test/i - failed: simple-symbol? at: [:bindings :form :local-symbol] spec: :clojure.core.specs.alpha/local-name
test/i - failed: vector? at: [:bindings :form :seq-destructure] spec: :clojure.core.specs.alpha/seq-binding-form
test/i - failed: map? at: [:bindings :form :map-destructure] spec: :clojure.core.specs.alpha/map-bindings
test/i - failed: map? at: [:bindings :form :map-destructure] spec: :clojure.core.specs.alpha/map-special-binding
```

What's going wrong? Can't I use `for` loops inside my macro definitions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`,@` should be `~@`.

```
user=> (defmacro foo []
  `(list ~@(for [i [1 2 3]] (+ 1 i))))
#'user/foo

user=> (macroexpand-1 '(foo))
(clojure.core/list 2 3 4)

user=> (foo)
(2 3 4)
```

Comment: The `#` is unrelated. There's no qualifying of variables needed here, since they're not introduced into the caller's scope. You've in fact just named a variable `i#`, which is legal but confusing. The only important change is the switch from `,` to `~`.